# How to ensure a channel read doesn't overtake any other case in a select

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have these 2 functions:

```golang
pointsQueue = make(chan *mongo.UpdateOneModel, 1000)

func UpdatePoints(username string, size int64) {
    pointsDifference := -1 * size
    update := bson.D{{"$inc", bson.D{{"pointsLeft", pointsDifference }}}}
    updateOp := mongo.NewUpdateOneModel()
    updateOp.SetFilter(bson.M{"user": username})
    updateOp.SetUpdate(update)
    pointsQueue <- updateOp
}

func updatePointsWorker() {
    var ctx = context.Background()
    ticker := time.NewTicker(dbBatchTimeout)
    var bulkRequests []mongo.WriteModel

    for {
        select {
        case req := <-pointsQueue:
            bulkRequests = append(bulkRequests, req)
        case <-ticker.C:
            if len(bulkRequests) > 0 {
                _, err := usersCollection.BulkWrite(ctx, bulkRequests)
                if err != nil {
                   fmt.Println(err.Error())
                }
                bulkRequests = nil
            }
    }
}
```

`UpdatePoints` can be called thousands of times in a short period of time (seconds), not allowing the ticker case to be selected and empty the bulkRequests array. How can I ensure that this case gets called even if the `UpdatePoints` is being called constantly? And most important that no request gets "lost" in the channel because it gets always overtaken by new writes

I have tried to bufferize the channel, but it didn't work. I have tried to set a treshold in the `req := <-pointsQueue:` case that calls bulkwrite if a certain amount of requests have been stored, but in this way I lose the requests sitting at the bottom of the channel because they'll be always preceded by new writes.

Comment: You don’t need to do anything. Select cases which can proceed are chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection, ensuring all cases eventually have an equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime should guarantee fairness so the ticker channel should not starve. However, even with that, your algorithm is speed dependent as too many reads from the `pointsQueue` channel may grow the slice to unacceptable levels. So, you should both use a timer and an upper limit on the length of the slice to make sure the slice is emptied properly.

```
empty:=func() {
  _, err := usersCollection.BulkWrite(ctx, bulkRequests)
  if err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }
  bulkRequests = nil
}

for {
        select {
        case req := <-pointsQueue:
            bulkRequests = append(bulkRequests, req)
            if len(bulkRequests) > limit {
               empty()
               ticker.Reset(dbBatchTimeout)
            }
        case <-ticker.C:
            if len(bulkRequests) > 0 {
                empty()
            }
    }
```